# Using C# .Net Gmail API, Why can i not print number of email in inbox?

Tags: c#

Im experimenting with the gmail api in C#.

My code looks like this:

```
    UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Messages.List("me");

                Console.WriteLine("Count Message: ");

                IList messages = request.Execute().Messages;

                if (messages != null && messages.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var message in messages)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(message);
                    }
                }
```

It returns Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message, 100 times. I understand that there are apperently 100 message in messages, but why? Im so confused.

Comment: The title suggests that you're just trying to print the count of messages, but the question doesn't.  What specifically are you trying to do?  Or are you asking why the default string representation of an object is the type name of that object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message` is a class (not a string) and  `Console.WriteLine(message);` would call and print it's `.ToString()` method which would lead to what you are currently seeing.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Gmail_1_1v1_1_1Data_1_1Message.html) you can find more about its properties. you may want to print its `Raw` property which is base64string of the message:

```
  foreach (var message in messages)
  {
        string body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(message.Raw));
        Console.WriteLine(body);
  }
```